# "adapt" in visibleWhen for menuContribution always returns false

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to follow [Lars Vogel's tutorial on natures](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProjectNatures/article.html#define-an-example-project-nature) and am stuck at the point where the `visibleWhen` for a menu is defined. When I add the following to my `command` definition in my `menuContribution`:

```xml
    <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <adapt
             type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
       </adapt>
    </visibleWhen>
```

my menu item never appears when right-clicking a project in Project Explorer.

I double-checked that I have all necessary things like `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, `org.eclipse.core.resources` and `org.eclipse.ui` as dependencies.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<iterate>` since what you are testing is a selection which may have multiple items:

For example this is one of the PDE API analysis tool command definitions:

```xml
<command
       commandId="org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui.convert.javadocs"
       style="push">
    <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <iterate>
          <adapt
                type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
             <test
                   property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                   value="org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.apiAnalysisNature">
             </test>
          </adapt>
       </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>
 </command>
```